# Why is this Dojo code not communicating with its' PHP file?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, dojo

In Firebug (with the FirePHP plugin) I noticed that there is no communication with the PHP file, and hence nothing happens...
Here is the Javascript:

```
// three parameters are required by Dojo!
function buildMenu(type, data, evt)
{
    var menuDOM = document.getElementById("colorselect");
    var nextColor, nextItem;

    // delete previous items in the color menu
    menuDOM.options.length = null;

    // split the data into an array of colors
    var colors = data.split(', ');

    // go through the returned array of colors
    for(var i = 0; i < colors.length; index++)
    {
        nextColor = colors[i];
        nextItem = new Option(nextColor);

        /* add the new item to the menu
         ("null" for IE5, "-1" for all other browsers) */
        try
        {
            menuDOM.add(nextItem, -1);
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            menuDOM.add(nextItem, null);
        }
    }
} // end of function buildMenu

// the function that calls bind to request data
function getColors(size)
{
    dojo.io.bind( {url: "shirtColors.php" + "?size=" + size,
                    load: buildMenu,
                    method: "GET",
                    mimetype: "text/plain"
                    } );
}<br /><br />
```

Here is the PHP:

```
<?php

    $shirtSize = $_GET["size"];

    // array for available colors (for each shirt size)
    $colors = array("large" => "black, yellow, green",
                    "medium" => "blue, purple, white, off-white, cream, bleached-white",
                    "small" => "orange, red, aqua, turqoise, aquamarine, light-blue");

    echo $colors[$shirtSize];
?><br /><br />
```

...and here is the html:
(Dojo is linked to online here, and the Dojo io library is imported)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Shirt Colors</title>

        <!-- link to dojo online -->
       <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.2/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

       <!-- javascript file -->
       <script type = "text/javascript" src = "shirtColors.js"></script>

       <!-- import the dojo io library -->
       <script type = "text/javascript">
        dojo.require("dojo.io.*");
       </script>

    </head>
    <body>

       <select onchange = "getColors(this.value);">
            <option value = "large">
                large shirt
            </option>
            <option value = "medium">
                medium shirt
            </option>
            <option value = "small">
                small shirt
            </option>
       </select>

       <select id = "colorselect"></select>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dojo.io.bind is a very old function.

The new and supported way for your use-case is to use  dojo.xhrGet or dojo.xhrPost

```
var deferred = dojo.xhrGet(
 {
    url: "shirtColors.php",
    content: {
      'size': size
    },
    handleAs: "text",
    load: buildMenu,
    error: function(error){
      //error handling code
    }
  }


);
```

Note that query params are passed as 'content'.

Modify your buildMenu function:

```
function buildMenu (data)
{
//data contains the text string for the data returned by PHP
}
```

See http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/xhrGet.html for more details

Comment: Ah, thanks for the help, now it works!  Except -- _only_ the the first part (**before** the first comma) of the String echoed from the PHP file is being set in the menu (example: just `black` for `"black, orange, grey"`).  Do I maybe have a typo, or am I applying Dojo incorrectly?

Comment: most likely the remaining data is not in the response text. You can examine the Response by clicking the Response tab in firebug Net tab for this request. or try this URL separately in the browser. If it is still an issue, I recommend returning data in JSON format since it is more structured than plain text.

Answer (score 1):

And change places of those files. If shirtolors is dependant of dojo.io it will not be loaded in.

```
    <!-- import the dojo io library -->
       <script type = "text/javascript">
        dojo.require("dojo.io.*");
       </script>



<!-- javascript file -->
       <script type = "text/javascript" src = "shirtColors.js"></script>
```